# How to improve the focus speed of camera?

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I use [dm77/barcodescanner](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) library to Scan QrCode. But When using This in my app, camera focus time is 1000L, and this is not optimal parameter for all phones.

How to improve the focus speed of camera?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question with help @TeunVR in github.
You must create a class and extends from ZXingScannerView and Override **setupCameraPreview** and **setAutoFocus** .

```
public class ZXingAutofocusScannerView extends ZXingScannerView {

private boolean callbackFocus = false ;

public ZXingAutofocusScannerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

@Override
    public void setupCameraPreview(CameraWrapper cameraWrapper) {

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters= cameraWrapper.mCamera.getParameters();
    if(parameters != null)
    {
      try {
          parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
          cameraWrapper.mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
      }catch (Exception e)
      {
          fallbackFocus = true ;
      }
       // cameraWrapper.mCamera.getParameters()

    }


    super.setupCameraPreview(cameraWrapper);
}
@Override
public void setAutoFocus(boolean state) {
    super.setAutoFocus(callbackFocus);
}
}
```

Now you must use this class instead **ZXingScannerView**.

```
public class SimpleScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
ZXingAutofocusScannerView.ResultHandler {

private ZXingAutofocusScannerView mScannerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    mScannerView = new ZXingAutofocusScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+rawResult.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
}
```

If You Use Koltin see this answer :

```
class ZXingAutofocusScannerView(context: Context) : 
ZXingScannerView(context) {
private val TAG = ZXingAutofocusScannerView::class.qualifiedName

private var callbackFocus = false

override fun setupCameraPreview(cameraWrapper: CameraWrapper?) {
    cameraWrapper?.mCamera?.parameters?.let{parameters->
        try {
            parameters.focusMode = 
 Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
            cameraWrapper.mCamera.parameters = parameters
        }catch(ex:Exception){
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to set CONTINOUS_PICTURE", ex)
            callbackFocus = true
        }
    }
    super.setupCameraPreview(cameraWrapper)
}

override fun setAutoFocus(state: Boolean) {
    super.setAutoFocus(callbackFocus)
}
}
```